# Monodevelop autocompletion doesnt show any unity class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, monodevelop, 2d-games

I've recently installed unity 5.3.2(with offline installer). Everything is working fine except the monodevelop. Its autocomplete feature does not list any of unity package classes.But when I open my project in visual studio it shows.

Comment: have you added "using UnityEngine;" in the top of your program? else restart monodevelop

Comment: yup monodevelop does that for me. I hv also restarted it. One that I forgot to add that i dont have the offline documentation of unity. Is this can be the problem?

Answer (score 4):

In Mono developer, right click on 'Assembly-Csharp' -> 'Options ', Under 'Build'->'General', change the 'Target framework':

[image: See Image]

Changing 'Target framework is the option that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you use unityScript then you should know :

> the Built-In Monodevelop of Unity 5.3 does not have autocomplete for
>   js

You can use this solution:

> Install Unity 5.3 in a new folder. Don't override Unity 5.2. After 5.3
>   is installed go to the installation folder and **delete the MonoDevelop**
>   **folder**. Now **copy the MonoDevelop folder from Unity 5.2 into the Unity**
>   **5.3 installation folder**, and there you have it. Now if you open any js or C# from inside Unity it will be opened in the previous version of
>   MonoDevelop and autocomplete will work for both.

Here is the refrence of this answer: [Unity 5.3 MonoDevelop autocomplete Not Working](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1114236/unity-53-monodevelop-autocomplete-not-working.html)

Comment: OP has tagged their question as c#